On the Definition of Simultaneous Substitution of Terms in FOL formula
Consider a firsr-order language $L$. Let $\varphi$ be a formula, $t$ a term and $x$ is a variable. We define the formula $\varphi[t/x]$, which denotes the formula obtained by substituting $t$ in place of $x$, as follows (here, $P$ is a $n$-ary predicate symbol and $\dagger$ denoted undefined; it does not belong to $L$).
$$\varphi[t/x]=
\begin{cases}
 P(t_1[t/x],\ldots,t_n[t/x])&\text{if}~\varphi~\text{is}~P(t_1,\ldots,t_n)\\
 t_1[t/x]=t_2[t/x]&\text{if}~\varphi~\text{is}~t_1=t_2\\
 \neg(\psi[t/x])&\text{if}~\varphi~\text{is}~\neg\psi\\
 \sigma[t/x]\land\tau[t/x]&\text{if}~\varphi~\text{is}~\sigma\land\tau\\
 \forall y\psi &\color{red}{\text{if}~\varphi~\text{is}~\forall y\psi}~\text{and}~y=x\\
 \dagger &\color{red}{\text{if}~\varphi~\text{is}~\forall y\psi},~y\ne x,~y~\text{occurs in}~t,~\text{and}~x~\text{occurs free in}~ψ\\
 \forall y(\psi[t/x])&\color{red}{\text{if}~\varphi~\text{is}~\forall y\psi},~y\ne x,~y~\text{doesn't occur in}~t~\text{or}~x~\text{isn't free in}~ψ
\end{cases}$$
The above definition is based on Westerståhl's recent book on logic. Now, after elaborating the definition, he writes that the above definition can be generalized in a straightforward manner to define $\varphi[t_1,\ldots,t_n/x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, i.e., simultaneous substitution of $t_i$'s in place of $x_i$'s. I can't figure out what the definition would look like in the quantifier-case. Can anyone help?

Anyone care to explain the welcome negative vote?

Basically, it is only a "notational" issue.
For $\varphi [s_1/x_1, \ldots, s_k/x_k]$, here are some cases:
$P(t_1[s_1/x_1, \ldots, s_k/x_k],\ldots,t_n[s_1/x_1, \ldots, s_k/x_k])$
$t_1[s_1/x_1, \ldots, s_k/x_k]=t_2[s_1/x_1, \ldots, s_k/x_k]$
and so on...
For the quantifier case $\forall y \psi$, we have to modify the proviso:

$\forall y (\psi  [s_1/x_1, \ldots, s_{i-1}/x_{i-1}, s_{i+1}/x_{i+1} \ldots s_k/x_k])$, if $y=x_i$ and $y$ does not occur in $s_1, \ldots, s_k$.

This is a case where the formula is less transparent that a verbal description.
In a nutshell, for formula $\forall y \psi$, substitution $s_i/x_i$ (i) cannot be performed when $x_i$ does not occur in the formula, and (ii) must not be performed when either $x_i$ is $y$ or $s_i$ is not free for $x_i$, i.e. $y$ occurs in $s_i$.
Added
Regarding Ebbinghaus' Mathematical Logic, page 48, there are no big differences.
The variables $x_i$ are ordered and different from each other and $x_i \in \text {free}(∃y \psi)$ means simply that $x_i$ occurs free in the formula [I've modified the symbols in order to be consistent with your example]. In addition, the author assumes that the substitution is not "trivial": $x_i \ne s_i$.
Then, in oder to avoid "capturing", i.e. the possible error that can occur if $s_i$ has $y$ inside, the author instead of excluding this case rename the quantified variable $y$ with $u$, where $u$ occurs nowhere, and exploits the fact that in this case $\exists y \psi$ and $\exists u (\psi[u/y])$ are equivalent.

The rest remains same? What about the other two conditions? Could you, if possible, write the definition more explicitly, so that I may compare?

Just to check whether I understand, do you mean the following?
$$(\forall y\psi)[t_1/x_1,\ldots,t_n/x_n]=
\begin{cases}
\forall y(\psi[t_1/x_1,\ldots,t_{i-1}/x_{i-1},t_{i+1}/x_{i+1},\ldots,t_n/x_n]) &\text{if}~y=x_i~\text{for some}~i~\text{and}~y~\text{does not occur in any}~t_j\
\dagger &\text{if}~y\ne x_i~\text{for all}~i~\text{or}~(y~\text{occurs in}~t_j~\text{for some}~j~\text{and}~x_j~\text{occurs free in}~ψ)\
\forall y(\psi[t_1/x_1,\ldots,t_n/x_n])&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

But this doesn't count as a generalization of the earlier definition. Not really straightforward.

So this means that (ignoring (i) for now) $s_i$ is substitutable for $x_i$ in $\varphi$ if $y\ne x_i$ and $y$ does not occur in $s_i$. Am I right?

@Ray -yes. Obviously we have to check it for every $i$, but for each one the check is the same. Obviously, we assume that the $x_i$ are different: this is why the specifications of the language says that we start with a denumerable list of variables. Thus, at most one of them can be equal to $y$.

Exactly. So, maybe, in the spirit of the original question, the correct formulation would be $$(\forall y\psi)[t_1/x_1,\ldots,t_n/x_n]=
\begin{cases}
\forall y\psi &\text{if}~y=x_i~\text{for all}~i~\text{(in this case}~n=1)\
\dagger &\text{if}~y\ne x_i~\text{for some}~i,~y~\text{occurs in}~t_i~\text{and}~x_i~\text{occurs free in}~ψ\
\forall y(\psi[t_1/x_1,\ldots,t_n/x_n ])&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Thanks for the help, and so much patience. There was an alternative formulation of the same in Ebbinghaus & Flum's book. But it was too complicated.
